# Can we create phased workflow in Sharepoint?

Tags: workflow, task-list

I am using a single tasklist at my work.
I would like to notify the administrator at different times i,e in phases.

For example, the data is presented in a tabular view categorized in to 5 phases.
So I would like to notify(email) the administrator whenever the user fills the phase 1, phase 4, phase 5 data.

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 1):

You can create a workflow on your task list and set it to automatically execute whenever an item in the list changes. Then, the first step in your workflow should be to check the value in the column that contains your phase number. Based on that value, your workflow can send the appropriate email.